# retrieve record in php with array

Tags: php, arrays

I have below output and I want to retrieve value of user_name. How to fetch this record.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 1
    [module_name] => Users
    [name_value_list] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => id
                    [value] => 1
                )

            [user_name] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => user_name
                    [value] => admin
                )

            [phone_mobile] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => phone_mobile
                    [value] => 
                )

        )

)

stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 159e9892-10fa-9b47-0134-5013c7c8a8ed
    [module_name] => Users
    [name_value_list] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => id
                    [value] => 159e9892-10fa-9b47-0134-5013c7c8a8ed
                )

            [user_name] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => user_name
                    [value] => ishani.lad
                )

            [phone_mobile] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => phone_mobile
                    [value] => 9033187384
                )

        )

)

stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 319f2420-86dc-6ebf-91e2-5790507595ee
    [module_name] => Users
    [name_value_list] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => id
                    [value] => 319f2420-86dc-6ebf-91e2-5790507595ee
                )

            [user_name] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => user_name
                    [value] => rajkumar.prajapati
                )

            [phone_mobile] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [name] => phone_mobile
                    [value] => 8460078459
                )

        )

)
```

with $value->id I can retrieve id but I want to retrieve value of user_name. For example ishani.lad

Comment: $value->name_value_list->user_name->value

Comment: @Saurabh Thanks. And Please Provide this in answer.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but this is not an array is an object obtained by json encoding, sometimes is better to work with objects, but you could also decode this to an associative array json_decode($value, true).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is object you can access it as below

```
$value->name_value_list->user_name->value
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if the object is stored in variable `$data` then

```
foreach($data as $row){
    echo $row->name_value_list->user_name->value.'<br/>';
}
```